# Replace group(1) by group(2) in Python

Tags: python, regex

I have this content:

```
[xxx]...[a]
[xxx]...[c]
[xxx]...[b]
```

That need replace to

```
[a]...[a]
[c]...[c]
[b]...[b]
```

My code here

```
p = re.compile(ur'\[(.*?)\].*?\[(.*?)\]', re.MULTILINE)
test_str = u"[xxx]...[a]\n[xxx]...[c]\n[xxx]...[b]"

m = re.findall(p, test_str)
print m
```

Output

```
[(u'xxx', u'a'), (u'xxx', u'c'), (u'xxx', u'b')]
```

How we can replace group(1) by group(2)

```
xxx => a
xxx => b
xxx => c
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please use `re.sub()` to do substitution with regex, findall() is only for searching:

```
In [14]: print p.sub(r'[\2]...[\2]', test_str)
[a]...[a]
[c]...[c]
[b]...[b]
```

Comment: Thank @piglei ,i have to capture all `p = re.compile(ur'(\[)(.*?)(\].*?\[)(.*?)(\])', re.MULTILINE)`   then `print p.sub(r'\1\4\3\4\5', test_str)` since my input is `Lorem ipsum dolor [xxx] sit amet, consectetur [a] adipiscing elit. Proin.` => `Lorem ipsum dolor [a] sit amet, consectetur [a] adipiscing elit. Proin.`

Answer (score 0):

I assume that `...` is a placeholder for other text.

```
test_str = u"[xxx]...[a]\n[xxx]...[c]\n[xxx]...[b]"
test_str2 = u"[xxx]abc1234[a]\n[xxx]xxx[c]\n[xxx]___[b]"

import re

def fixit(test):
    list1=test.split()
    list2=[]
    for st in list1:
        a=re.findall('\[\w\]',st)[0]
        list2.append(re.sub('\[xxx\]',a,st))  # re.sub(pattern, replacement, string)
    return '\n'.join(list2)

print fixit(test_str)
print
print fixit(test_str2)
```

Output:

```
[a]...[a]
[c]...[c]
[b]...[b]

[a]abc1234[a]
[c]xxx[c]
[b]___[b]
```

Comment: `p = re.compile(ur'(\[)(.*?)(\].*?\[)(.*?)(\])', re.MULTILINE)`
`print p.sub(r'\1\4\3\4\5', test_str)` will save tons of time

Comment: Ty. Good solution.